# Search datatable based on dropdown and input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have created a datatable and above a dropdown with an input field.

I would like to sort based on the action that I choose with the drop down.

The search  within the column is working correctly. I would like to search using the action of the dropdown menu. Find below my viable example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('.datatable-responsive').DataTable();

  /**
   * Dropdown with Input Field
   */
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var changePercentageInput = parseInt($('#changePercentageInput').val(), 10);
      var changePerc = parseFloat(data[4]) || 0; // use data for the changePerc column

      if ((isNaN(changePercentageInput)) ||
        (changePercentageInput <= changePerc)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );

  $('#changePercentageInput').keyup(function() {
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Global stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- /global stylesheets -->
  <!-- Core JS files -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /core JS files -->
  <!-- Load plugin -->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /load plugin -->
  <!-- Theme JS files -->
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/sliders/ion_rangeslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/marcpre/demo_cryptoscreener/master/_other/layout_html/global_assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment_locales.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="navbar-top">
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div class="page-content pt-0">
    <!-- Default ordering -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label><b>% Change:</b></label>
                <div class="mb-1">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle legitRipple" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px);">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Below</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Below or equal</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Above</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Above or equal</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Equal</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Not equal</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="changePercentageInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CHG %">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive dataTable" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Stock</th>
              <th>SYMBOL</th>
              <th>LAST</th>
              <th>CHG %</th>
              <th>CHG</th>
              <th>HIGH</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr role="row" class="odd">
              <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">1</td>
              <td>USD/BTC</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>0.00061720</td>
              <td>-181.40%</td>
              <td>-0.00001140</td>
              <td>0.00065050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="even">
              <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">2</td>
              <td>EUR/Rubel</td>
              <td>EUR</td>
              <td>0.00767000</td>
              <td>-166.70%</td>
              <td>-0.00013000</td>
              <td>0.00803000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="odd">
              <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">3</td>
              <td>Yen/USD</td>
              <td>Yen</td>
              <td>0.00000000</td>
              <td>-0.1112%</td>
              <td>0.00000000</td>
              <td>0.00000000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="even">
              <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">4</td>
              <td>Yen/EUR</td>
              <td>Yen</td>
              <td>0.00000000</td>
              <td>0.01%</td>
              <td>0.00000000</td>
              <td>0.00000000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="odd">
              <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">5</td>
              <td>Rubel/Yen</td>
              <td>Rubel</td>
              <td>0.00658300</td>
              <td>28.90%</td>
              <td>0.00001900</td>
              <td>0.00707600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="even">
              <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">6</td>
              <td>EUR/USD</td>
              <td>EUR</td>
              <td>0.00000040</td>
              <td>256.41%</td>
              <td>0.00000001</td>
              <td>0.00000042</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- /default ordering -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions how to link the action of the dropdown field to the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't get how you would select from the div dropdown so added my own 'select' dropdown, you can change it as needed. Also the parseFloat and parseInt failed on 'Equal' so I changed it both to parseFloat.

```
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle legitRipple" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px);">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Below</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Below or equal</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Above</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Above or equal</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Equal</a>
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Not equal</a>
                      </div>
                      <select id="operator" name="oper">
                          <option value="<" class="dropdown-item">Below</option>
                          <option value="<=" class="dropdown-item">Below or equal</option>
                          <option value=">" class="dropdown-item">Above</option>
                          <option value=">=" class="dropdown-item">Above or equal</option>
                          <option value="==" class="dropdown-item">Equal</option>
                          <option value="!=" class="dropdown-item">Not equal</option>
                      </select>
         </div>
```

JS Below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('.datatable-responsive').DataTable();
        var op = "<";
        /**
         * Dropdown with Input Field
         */
        var operators = {
            "==": function (a, b) { return a == b; },
            "<=": function (a, b) { return a <= b; },
            ">=": function (a, b) { return a >= b; },
            "<": function (a, b) { return a < b; },
            ">": function (a, b) { return a > b; },
            "!=": function (a, b) { return a != b; }
        };

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var changePercentageInput = parseFloat($('#changePercentageInput').val(), 10);
                var changePerc = parseFloat(data[4]) || 0; // use data for the changePerc column

                if ((isNaN(changePercentageInput)) || (operators[op](+changePercentageInput, +changePerc))) {
                    console.log(changePercentageInput + " " + changePerc);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        );
        $('#operator').on('change', function () {
            op = this.value;
            table.draw();
        });
        $('#changePercentageInput').keyup(function () {
            table.draw();
        });
    });
```